# Possible (literal) meanings of "get high/get by"

Tags: idioms, phrasal-verbs

There's a single "High By the Beach", recently issued by Lana Del Rey, which has the following chorus:

```
All I wanna do is get high by the beach,
Get high by the beach, get high.
All I wanna do is get by by the beach,
Get by – baby, baby, bye, bye.
```

The question is: what other meanings/synonyms of the idiom "to get high" [besides the obvious "to get euphoric (by smoking weed)"] are possible here in the context of the lyrics/music video: https://youtu.be/QnxpHIl5Ynw? May it be interpreted literally as simply "to get high enough somewhere over a beach far from the rest of the world"? Does the meaning change through repetition? And the same goes for "get by" phrasal verb, first followed by "by the beach" and then used on its own. What meanings may it have here? Very much looks like a play on words, doesn't it?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Unfortunately, this question risks getting close-voted since it is fairly opinion-based. Lyrics interpretations are very flaky since they depend greatly on people's interpretation rather than concrete context. Additionally, it may be argued that dictionary definitions of "get high" may be all you need to work out the various potential meanings of the lyrics in question. The [Help Centre](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) will answer your questions about what is considered on and off-topic here.

Comment: @JMB Thank you for your prompt reply. I do understand that the whole story is very opinion-based – I just want to know whether native speakers can notice here some obvious word play or something of the kind (like, say, in "Time flies like an arrow"). For example, is there a noticeable difference between "get by by the beach", "get by the beach" and "get by"? I guess there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpreting song lyrics and poetry can by tricky, since it's hard to say what the writer meant in a particularly poetic passage.

However, this is not such a case. I'm 99% sure Lana Del Rey literally means that all she wants to do was get high (become intoxicated on some drug of her choice) in the vicinity of a sandy ocean vista.

This is not high poetry.

To expand on the idea a little more, "to get high" generally means to enter a state of intoxication or euphoria, usually but not always by means of a psychoactive drug. Sometimes people say they are "high on life", or "high on your love." I have also heard people talk about getting a "high" from working out or playing competitive sports.

It isn't usually used in the sense of "ascend in altitude", although you could say something like "I want to get high in the sky in an airplane." Some people might still think you're implying you want to get high on drugs, though.

The line "Get by, by the beach" could mean she wants to "get by" - which in my opinion, in this context means to manage or cope despite hardship - near the beach. It could also be a simple repetition of the word to fill out the meter, meaning just "get by the beach."

Comment: One can "get high" without consuming intoxicating substance, but also by participating in an activity that causes endorphins to be released (sex, for instance).

Comment: In other words, "get high" can be used figuratively in the second degree.

Comment: "Not **high** poetry" - is that a pun?

Comment: @VictorBazarov It is now!

Comment: @AaronBrown So, apparently, there's no way for a native speaker to interpret "get high" here in the most literal way possible as, say, "high on a cliff by the ocean" – the only possible (or most probable) meaning is just "get intoxicated" or "get euphoric" (by any means). Okay, thank you – that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Not only sex :) but, say, meditation as well (though it's a rather rare way of getting high, I presume). So, what I though of as a possible meaning in the context of the song (and video) was "to meditate, doze off, get out of reach", not just "to get stoned".

Comment: @all thank you all – I was looking for a word play here and it looks like I eventually found one :)

Comment: @Buckminster Yes, when people say "get high" they mean "enter a state of intoxication or euphoria". I'll expand on that a little more. It doesn't really ever mean "raise your physical altitude."

Comment: @Buckminster added more details in the answer. There is wordplay, but it's not particularly subtle!

Comment: @AaronBrown: It's not "get by the beach", it's "get by **by** the beach" (twice the preposition), which means "merely exist close to the sandy ocean shore"

Comment: That's true, although it could also just be "fill the song meter by repetition."

Comment: Okay, I got the whole idea about "getting high" – it's just an idiom (a well-known one) and no literal meaning behind it. And what about "get by" here? What is the most probable meaning that it may have from the point of view of a native speaker? Is it simply "arrive/find oneself", or "escape/evade", or even "manage/cope", or maybe all of them? Of course I do understand that it is very opinion-based, but I'd like to know your opinions.

Comment: @VictorBazarov You managed to answer my question while I was busy formulating it :) So, the most obvious meaning here is just "to get close to a shore". Okay, it seems to be the case.

Comment: @Buckminster I think there is actually some wordplay in that line, IMO it could be a play on "get by, by the beach" as in "cope with you being a bad boyfriend" in the song's context.

Comment: I don't agree with Aaron that it could be just "repetition to fill the meter", I think it's "*get by* (as in "struggle to exist", "manage with difficulty to accomplish something") by the beach".

Comment: Why couldn't it be? As with any song or poem, there can be multiple interpretations.

Comment: Well, what I myself thought on the topic prior to asking the question is that in the case of "get by" all possible meanings are present (first of all, "to arrive/find oneself at the beach" and "to cope/manage with difficulties"), so it made me think that probably "get high" here also could have several meanings, since the lines are built similarly and it might somehow "shift" the idiomatic meaning of "get high" by analogy, so to say. I wondered if native speakers might see it the same way. Obviously, not.

Comment: Thank you, Aaron and Victor, for sharing your thoughts on the topic – I guess, now the situation is quite clear.